# How to use HMR with SASS and ng2 style loading?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, sass-loader

Changes to my SCSS files, while appropriately loaded onto the page, result in a full page reload rather than HMR for the css (hot module replacement of the changed stylesheet). How can I get HMR to work with Angular2?

Applicable webpack config (postcss for autoprefixer):

```
{
  test: /\.ts$/,
  loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
},
{
  test: /\.s?css$/,
  loader: 'raw!postcss?sourceMap=inline!sass?sourceMap'
},
```

Component style implementation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-route',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ],
})
```

Comment: Well, I've made some people on the Angular team aware: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11942. We'll see if they choose to make it a priority.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same problem here...

I guess with the current `angular2-template-loader` it's just not possible, because this loader combo base on `angular2-template-loader` simply change `styleUrls` to `styles` and put the compiled scss code inline:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-route',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styles: [ '.home{color:red}' ],
})
```

So it's a part of JS code instead of static CSS.  Ng2 will render these code in runtime.  This also means `ExtractTextPlugin` has no use on that...

I'm now trying to use [`css-loader`'s CSS Module](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#local-scope) instead of Ng2's dynamic rendering to achieve scoped CSS. I'm still having some problems with TypeScript but it should work.

#### home.component.ts:

```
const klasses = require('./home.component.scss')

@Component({
  selector: 'home-route',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  klasses = klasses
}
```

#### home.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="klasses.home"></div>
```

IMO, this solution works but is really complicated.  But I can't found a better solution until something like [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) come to Ng2 world...

### P.S.

What I'm worried about is how does `ts-loader` / `awesome-typescript-loader` work. Although not yet be sure, I guess if any css file was modified, the ts file require it will also deem modified then be recompiled, which finally cause a full refreshing...

Comment: But isn't the whole point of modules that there is a numeric reference from the transpired .ts file to the actual data - so you can reload it regardless of whether it is actually embedded into the .js file. I'm thoroughly confused and don't even know what's supposed to happen despite spending the past hour reading all about it :-/